# Java: move all paths to a separate file

Tags: java, file, path

In my program, I access files in a relative way many times in different classes.

And I do not want to create a `private static final String PATH` variable every time.

```
File file = new File(PATH);
```

How can I make all the paths to a separate file in java (in which I will indicate all the relative paths)  so that I can access it from anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a small method:

```
public static String getValue(String key) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("src\\main\\resources\\app.properties"));
        return properties.getProperty(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making an Enum and put all the paths in it.
something like

```
public enum Paths{
    FILE1("path_to_file"),
    FILE2("path_to_file")
}
```

Comment: This is one of the solution methods. but I would like to use the `app.properties` file and specify the parameters there in a key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class Util.java and add all static variables as public inside that class.
For example

```
public class Util {
    public static final String PATH_ONE = "C:\\location\\filepath1";
    public static final String PATH_TWO = "C:\\location\\filepath2";
}
```

Access these paths from any classes like this

```
File file = new File(Util.PATH_ONE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to use the `app.properties` file.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like Spring? Better to mention that you want to use app.properties in your question.

Comment: I apologize that I did not write this detail right away!